# How to use TOP in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7

I've this code below :

```
public function findAllByPagePlain($limit, $offset, $q, $category_id, $column, $order)
    {
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT TOP $limit p.* FROM ec_product p ";
        $keywordQuery = "(p.name REGEXP '$q' OR p.status REGEXP '$q' OR p.description REGEXP '$q') ";
        if ($category_id != -1) {
            $query = $query . ", product_category pc WHERE pc.product_id=p.id AND pc.category_id=$category_id ";
            if ($q != "") $query = $query . "AND " . $keywordQuery;
        } else {
            if ($q != "") $query = $query . "WHERE " . $keywordQuery;
        }
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY p." . $column . " " . $order . " OFFSET $offset ";
        return $this->db->get_list($query);
    }
```

I'm trying to use TOP to fetch first `n rows` from my database. but it keeps giving me an error saying

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'. ) )
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: `SELECT TOP ... FROM TABLE ...ORDER BY ....` if you need to use `DISTINCT` then use a subquery first and then use `TOP`

Comment: @Sami and where i should write the ```DISTINCT``` ?

Comment: In the subqyery

Comment: @Sami can you write the full query for me ? I can't understand you

Comment: Something like: `SELECT TOP n Columns FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table) T ORDER BY SomeOrder`

Comment: This is pretty scary. It is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange I'm just trying to get it work, and I can't . Can u edit the code for me ?

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to output `$query` to see what the query looks like?

Comment: ```SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM ec_product p TOP 10 ORDER BY p.id DESC OFFSET 0``` Here is the query when I echo it

Comment: "Just getting it to work" without fixing the major security hole is a bad way to approach writing code. And then being forced to ask others to fix it for you because you can't debug it is kind of sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

- The reason for your `Incorrect syntax near '0'` error is the fact, that you are not using the correct syntax for [OFFSET ... FETCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) clauses. I think, that you are trying to implement a paging solution, so use the `OFFSET ... FETCH` clauses instead of the `TOP` clause.
- `REGEXP` syntax is part of MySQL, for MS SQL Server you should use `LIKE` or `PATINDEX()`
- As an important note, rewrite your code and use parameterized statements to prevent SQL injection attacks (as is mentioned in the comments).

Change the function like in the example below to solve the `Incorrect syntax near '0'` error:

```
<?php
public function findAllByPagePlain($limit, $offset, $q, $category_id, $column, $order)
    {
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM ec_product p ";
        $keywordQuery = "(p.name LIKE '%$q%' OR p.status LIKE '%$q%' OR p.description LIKE '%$q%') ";
        if ($category_id != -1) {
            $query = $query . ", product_category pc WHERE pc.product_id=p.id AND pc.category_id=$category_id ";
            if ($q != "") $query = $query . "AND " . $keywordQuery;
        } else {
            if ($q != "") $query = $query . "WHERE " . $keywordQuery;
        }
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY p." . $column . " " . $order . " OFFSET ". $offset . " ROWS FETCH NEXT " . $limit. " ROWS ONLY";
        return $this->db->get_list($query);
    }
?>
```